# Facebook Like Button as Share Button

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I need use a facebook like button on my site. But this site have a dinamicall data. 
Exists any thing to use a facebook like as facebook share whit metadata params:
Eaxmple :

I use a share button like this:
http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p[title]=titulo&p[summary]=descripcion&p[url]=http://mydominio.com/compartir&p[images][0]=http://mydominio.com/imagen.jpg

Answer (score 4):

The http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php is being deprecated.  You should use the new Like button (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/).

If you have your OG tags specified correctly, the user who clicks the like button will be presented with a "share" dialog which will post a link to the site onto the user's feed.  Anyone subscribed to that feed will see the link.